# Can we extend the idea that if $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$, then $ab \geq 0$?

Tags: inequality

It is known that if $$|a+b|=|a|+|b|$$ then we can find the solution by simply observing that we can instead solve the inequality $$a b \geq 0$$

My question is, if $|a+b+c|=|a|+|b|+|c|$, then what would be the '3 degree version' of the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third degree (or higher) version is "all nonnegative" or "all nonpositive".

Answer (score 1):

The totally general version of this (which works with arbitrarily many vectors, as well as in $n$ dimensions) is "all the vectors are positive scalar multiples of each other."