# How can it be shown that $ab ≥ 0$ if and only if $|a + b| = |a| + |b|$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking about using something like this
If $( c > 0 )$, $ ( |a + b| < c ) $ implies $( -c < a + b < c )$.

Comment: Just consider the possible cases for the signs of $a$ and $b$. Both directions of the iff can be proved this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equality holds in triangle inequality iff both numbers are positive, both are negative or one is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/equality-holds-in-triangle-inequality-iff-both-numbers-are-positive-both-are-ne) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clvert%20a%2Bb%5Crvert%3D%5Clvert%20a%5Crvert%2B%5Clvert%20b%5Crvert%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24ab%5Cge%200%24&p=1). Note there are also other duplicates, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [if $a,b\in R$ and $b\neq 0$, show that $\lvert a + b\rvert = \lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert$ if an only if $ab\geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3559583/602049), and several quite similar questions, e.g., [Why does solution to $|a| + |b| = |a+b|$, where $a$ and $b$ are linear equations, satisfy $ab\ge 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3813879/602049), [Can we extend the idea that if $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$, then $ab \geq 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1456591/602049), etc.